# Python is not recognized in Jenkins

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins

Python is not recognized in Jenkins when running a .bat file. Within the .bat file "python test.py" is called and it raises the below exception. But from the terminal it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I think python is installed in the context of user admin.

Comment: create a startup script in your job to set the paths. You're not running as your user but another user with a blank profile

Answer (score 1):

try to add the python installation directory in path environment variable through jenkins.

To add this go to manage jenkins -> configure system -> Environment Variables and add

`path=%path%;<python executable path>`

Comment: It's not working. I gave a name and the path of Python as the value

Comment: you have to give the parent directory path of python if this not works, then add the python path in system as well user environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your script please give the path where python is installed and followed by your command:- (please follow below)

```
@echo off
"Path where your Python exe is stored\python.exe" "Path where your Python script is stored\script a.py"
```